# Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

Tags: php, mysqli

Alright so I am getting an error that there is no function called num_rows for some reason, anyone knows why?

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE sender='".$this->getUsername()."' LIMIT $page_count,5");
$count = $result->num_rows();
```

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::num_rows()

I attemped to search for the problem online but couldnt find any successful results regarding this issue.

Comment: just use `$result->num_rows`

Comment: Thats because there is no method called `->num_rows()` but there is a property called `->num_rows`

Comment: 3 seconds on Google wouldn't have hurt.

Comment: this is a terrible question and didn't search the error. I honestly don't know where you get off on saying it should stay here and a good question. Edit: Now you deleted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There's no `num_rows` method in `MySQLi_Result`. Check `MySQLi_Result` up in PHP's documentation: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.mysqli-result.php

Perhaps you mean `mysqli_num_rows` static method or even the `num_rows` property (in which case you should use without the parenthesis):

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE sender='".$this->getUsername()."' LIMIT $page_count,5");
$count = $result->num_rows;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because its not a method. Its a variable. From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php),

```
Object oriented style

int $mysqli_result->num_rows;
```

So in your case, you should do

```
$result = $sql->query("SELECT * FROM private_messages WHERE sender='".$this->getUsername()."' LIMIT $page_count,5");
$count = $result->num_rows;
```